# Boolean indexing with whole df of bools

Tags: python, pandas

I have a df of 168 rows x 60 columns of True/False

Sample here

Datedf

```
Date_Month_0    Date_Month_1    Date_Month_2
0   False   False   False
1   False   True    False
2   False   False   True
```

I have another df of the same shape, 168 rows x 60 columns of float

Sample here: Volumedf

```
Volume_Month_0  Volume_Month_1  Volume_Month_2
0   None    1000    1
1   2000    None    None
2   2000    2000    500
```

I'm trying to do boolean indexing using the whole Datedf. I'd like to keep only the values which are a True in my first df.

I've tried to multiply the 2 df but I get a df of NaN

```
df = Volumedf[Datedf] doesn't work --> df of NaN
df = Volumedf * Datedf doesn't work --> df of NaN
```

What am I doing wrong ? How should I do it ?

I expect my final result to be: (the NaN can also be null)

```
    1       2       3
0   NaN     NaN     NaN
1   NaN     None    NaN
2   NaN     NaN     500
```

Comment: Please indicate the final result. Is `df2.where(df.values)` what you want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're only trying to mask, then you can do so on the underlying arrays,

```
# pandas >=0.24
df2.where(df.to_numpy(), '')
# older versions
df2.where(df.values, '')

  Volume_Month_0 Volume_Month_1 Volume_Month_2
0                                             
1                          None               
2                                          500
```

If you need NaNs,

```
df2.where(df.to_numpy())

  Volume_Month_0 Volume_Month_1 Volume_Month_2
0            NaN            NaN            NaN
1            NaN           None            NaN
2            NaN            NaN            500
```

Another option is to multiply the DataFrame and the array mask:

```
df2 * df.values

  Volume_Month_0 Volume_Month_1 Volume_Month_2
0                                             
1                          None               
2                                          500
```

The reason we need to use the array is because the columns of `df` and `df2` are different,  so pandas tries to align them and fails (since they're different), the end result is a DataFrame full of NaNs. When multiplying by NumPy array, the only requirement is that the shape is to be the same.

Comment: thank you, why was the multiplication not working ? Is it because the columns aren't the same ? But when I rename them to have them match, it doesn't work either

Comment: It should work, unless your two dataframes have different row indices.

Comment: @yeye This worked for me because `df2` is comprised of strings. Maybe `df2.astype(str) * df` would have worked for you. The other possibility is that, as Quang said, the row indexes aren't the same.

Answer (score 0):

You could convert your dataframe to bumpy and use the first as a mask for the second.

**DataFrame to numpy**
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_numpy.html

**Numpy mask**
https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/maskedarray.html

Take a look at **pandas mask** too. Maybe it is possible directly with pandas: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html

Comment: What is bumpy? ;)

Comment: Bumpy is a fork of numpy which does nothing but changing it's name. Vastly underestimated :)